# Why can't the worker Pods can't see Hosts created in a Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a 3 node, 1 pod per each nodes Kubernetes Cluster. Cluster and Nodes are created by Minikube.
Once the pods are created, i run the following commandes in the master pod using the scrip file:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /common.sh

echo "$(hostname -i) spark-master" >> /etc/hosts

/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip spark-master --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

and the following commandes are run in the worker pod using a scrip file also:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset SPARK_MASTER_PORT

if ! getent hosts spark-master; then
  sleep 5
  exit 0
fi

/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077 --webui-port 8081



memory = '10g'
pyspark_submit_args = ' --driver-memory ' + memory + ' pyspark-shell'
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args`
```

However the the command getent hosts spark-master is unable to obtain the spark-master created by the master pod. They are all in the same namespace Default.

Here are my Ingress, Master deployment, Worker Deployment and service YAML files:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: spark-ingress
spec:
 rules:
  - http:
     paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
         service:
          name: spark-master-service
          port:
           number: 8080
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: spark-master
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: spark-master
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: spark-master
  spec:
   affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
     requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
       - matchExpressions:
         - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
           operator: In
           values:
            - k8cluster
   containers:
    - name: spark-master
      image: spark:3.2.0
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c","/spark-master"]
      ports:
       - containerPort: 7077
       - containerPort: 8080
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: spark-worker
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: spark-worker
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: spark-worker
  spec:
   affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
     requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
       - matchExpressions:
         - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
           operator: In
           values:
            - k8cluster-m02
            - k8cluster-m03
   containers:
    - name: spark-worker
      image: spark:3.2.0
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c","/spark-worker"]
      ports:
       - containerPort: 8081
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: spark-master-service
spec:
 selector:
  app: spark-master
 type: NodePort
 ports:
  - name: wabui
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: spark
    port: 7077
    targetPort: 7077
```

I have tried the go in the terminal of the Worker pods and type de getent hosts command. It does not in fact see the Spark-Master host. However, In the terminal of the Master pods, it is available.